# ggplot2: grouped bar graph with groupby results as one bar and the total as second bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b', 'c','d','e'), col2 = c(3,1,2,3,1), col3 = c('yes','yes','no','no','yes))
```

Essentially I would like a grouped bar chart where the first group is the number of times a value occurs in column2 and has a value of yes in column3, and the second bar is the total number of times the value occurs in column2, regardless of group.

[image: hand drawn desired bar graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a grouped summary to compute `yes` and `total`, pivot to long, and map the pivoted column to `fill`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(col2) %>%
  summarize(
    yes = sum(col3 == "yes"),
    total = n()
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    yes:total,
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "n"
  ) %>%
  mutate(response = fct_rev(response)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    aes(col2, n, fill = response),
    position = "dodge"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7570b3", "#1b9e77")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]